# How can I find a certain time interval in every day using PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

In my student attendance project, in everyday in between 9.45 am to 10.30 am, a teacher should mark their students attendance.

So, a teacher should able to mark their attendance only on that time. Rest of the time students list should be disabled.

Here I am facing an issue to find that server current time reached in between 9.45am to 10.30am everyday.

```
$now = time();  
$today = strtotime('9:50');
//do not know how to find current date with time interval 9.45am and 10.30am
if (($today - $now) > 0) {
    $status = "disabled";
} else {
    $status = "active";
}
```

Please help me to find a solution for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$current_time = date('h:i:s a'); //now
$start = "9:50 am";
$finish = "10:30 am";
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $current_time);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $start);
$date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i a', $finish);
if ($date1 > $date2 && $date1 < $date3)
{
    $status = "active";
} else {
    $status = "disabled";
}
```

to test with out waiting for the correct time you can set the `$current_time` like so:

```
$current_time = "10:31 am";
```

I hope its self-explanatory, but if you have any questions, ask. and\or see the [dateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class

Comment: Using Carbon is a better way to deal with dates and time than DateTime class,

Comment: i disagree; but feel free to post an answer using carbon @AdityaThakur

Comment: sir, it doesnt work, when i echo $date1, $date2, $date3 nothing is showing.

Comment: you dont echo them, there is no need to. `$status` is the value you are using

Comment: a small doubt,  $current_time shows this time (04:42:58 am). my system time is ‎Friday, ‎May ‎3, ‎2019 ‎10:15 AM

Comment: it uses the server time, if  the sever time is not what you want you can change the time zone